# Not able to install bower using npm on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, bower

I am not able to install bower.

Steps carried out :

- Installed node.js (current stable version v0.10.12)
- Installed npm using apt-get (v1.1.4)

Tried installing bower using :
    npm install bower

I get the possible node.js incompatible error. 
The weird thing is that the error log indicates that the script went to the node directory & tried node -v to get an old version of node.js (v0.6.19) though when I do so manually I get v.0.10.12.

Error Log :

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: bower
npm ERR! No valid targets found.
npm ERR! Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /usr/share/node-v0.10.12/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-25-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/share/node-v0.10.12
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: bower
npm ERR! message No valid targets found.
npm ERR! message Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/share/node-v0.10.12/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Need a way to install bower. Any ideas ?

Comment: Your node version needs to be >= 0.8.0.  EDIT: Re-read the question, looks like you have conflicting node versions.  Try cleaning out all your node bins and re-installing 0.10.0.  Or use a node version manager.

Comment: That worked !!! Used the node version manager method. Thanks !

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue on ubuntu 12.04 here is how I fixed it:

As GabLeRoux mentioned, Node version manager requires curl package to be installed and therefore you might need to install curl before:

```
sudo apt-get install curl -y
```

1) Clear NPM's cache:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```

2) Install a little helper called 'n' ([node version manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n))

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

3) Install latest stable NodeJS version

```
sudo n stable
```

4) Install Bower again

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Comment: Note, n requires curl, `sudo apt-get install curl -y`

Comment: @GabLeRoux I have edited the post to include what you mentioned in your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, because you must install it as superuser:

```
sudo npm install bower
```

You must type in your su password.

Comment: Should not install bower as a super user!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the linux binary from nodejs.org. Available for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions and installs with NPM:

http://nodejs.org/download/

This should prevent any node/npm version conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

For Cent OS users -

I first had to update NPM to get around this, and was getting errno 34 for bower on CentOS 7

```
sudo npm install -g npm
sudo npm install -g bower
```

If you get `sudo npm command not found`, you can edit `/etc/sudoers` to include npm bin path

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```